# Free tools that automatically reformat whole C/C++ source files in VS2008 on save?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, reformat

I'm looking for a tool (macro, extension) for Visual Studio 2008 that would reformat the source code (C/C++) when you save the file.

Comment: Have you tried CTRL+K, CTRL+D  ?

Comment: It's CTRL+K, CTRL+F in the C++ editor, but yeah, I was about to suggest that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AStyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) was my first hit on Google. Looks reasonable. You can tie that to a keyboard event under 'External Tools' in Visual Studio. (I suspect writing/recording a small macro that formats and saves the file is easy, as is rebinding that to Ctrl-S)

See also [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841075/best-c-code-formatter-beautifier,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841075/best-c-code-formatter-beautifier) which also recommends AStyle.

Comment: Sorry but AStyle has a big issue handling Unicode source files - it does garbage them.

Comment: Seems to be fixed in SVN: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2864811&group_id=2319&atid=102319

Comment: and it requires PERL

Answer (score 1):

Wasn't it so that you can define a "macro" in Visual Studio yourself? If so, you could try making one to do something like `Ctrl+A -> Ctrl+K Ctrl+F -> Ctrl+S` meaning `select all, reformat, save` and then bind it to your `Ctrl+S`. I'm not sure, but I think it wouldn't be too complicated.