# C++ Formatting like Visual Studio C# formatting

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, formatting, intellisense

I like the way Visual Studio (2008) formats C# code; unfortunately it seems it doesn't behave in the same way when writing C++ code.

For example, when I write a code in this way:

```
class Test {
public:
    int x;
    Test() {this->x=20;}
    ~Test(){}
};
```

in C# (ok this is C++ but you can understand what I mean), this part:

```
Test() {this->x=20;}
```

Will become:

```
Test() { this->x=20; }
```

This is obviously a stupid example, but there are a lot of things where putting brackets in correct position, indenting code and other things with my own hands becomes boring.

I can obviously change editor if you suggest me a good one for C++ code, I would like to find something with these features:

- Intellisense (like vs, at least similar)
- Custom class coloring (in C=C# they are cyan, why are they black in C++?)
- Wordwrap (possibly)
- Documentation when you mouse over a method/variable
- Auto formatting (when you close a bracket like "}" in C# you'll get
  everything well formatted)

Obviously I can find other features, but this is what is in my mind at the moment.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Fairly sure this is a duplicate, however my google-fu is letting me down and I need to go do some work, but I'm fairly certain this exact question has been asked before.

Comment: The C++ IDE has a *very* different editor.  Before you spend serious money on add-ins, check out what VS2010 does.  It has a completely re-written editor, maybe the IDEs will have more in common.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but isn't VS2010 still in beta?When it will come out (I know is soon... I would like to know what "soon" means in this case)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using AStyle extension for VS2012 and I'm happy with it.
It's free :)

Comment: If you want a free solution, this is the way to go guys. I'm using it. The question is about visual studio 2010 but I keep the editor up to date so I mark this as the answer.

Comment: AStyle extension is also avaiable for VS2010

Answer (score 12):

Select the code-text and press CTRL+K-F in Visual Studio - That's it :)

Comment: My 2 cents -- Having to remember to press CTRL+K-F after every change to a file is a pain.  Sure it is not as bad as having to go through the code and add extra formatting in, but it is still a pain that C# coders don't have because VS automatically updates the format as they type.

Comment: well does happen with c# code as well, specially if you copy paste.. among other reasons. i also use CTRL+K-F for c# and xml/xsd as well as config files..

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the Tools->Options->Text Editor settings you can control *some* of what you want, but I don't think as much as you'd like. Instead of changing editors, if the code style is that important, why not run it through a pretty printer? [Check out this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841075/best-c-code-formatter-beautifier) for ideas.

Comment: My other thought is that it may be easier to adapt to the editor than to make the editor adapt to you.  I have spent a lot of time in Visual Studio and actually like its defaults.  (Yes you should put spaces on the insides of your braces! heh)

Comment: That's a good suggestion, the problem is that I would like to "auto format" my class/block/otherThings after } or ;... "UniversalIndentGUI" could work with notepad?I'll check it (but if I'm not wrong, I'll lose a lot of features that VS has)

Answer (score 2):

You'll struggle to find a much better editor than Visual Studio for writing c++ code.  You will get used to it eventually.  If you really cannot cope, then take a look at [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/).  It is a little pricey but it will beautify your code colours.

Comment: You are right but, for my way of thinking, writing code should be something that I like... that's why I'm looking for something like this, because after a lot of lines, you'll get bored from things like "put a space after your ; and before }" while the editor can do it for you.

Visual Assist looks very nice, but the price is too high for me, I'm a student actually...

Answer (score 1):

SlickEdit is a highly configurable editor and offers tagging functionality (what VS calls "Intellisense") that blows VS and Visual Assist out of the water.  Plus there's a cool preview window that shows you the definition for the thing under the cursor, which is lightning fast (and you can turn off if you want).

I use vim these days, though, which is even more highly configurable, and I'll never go back.  It's a little trickier to get configured well, though.

Comment: Visual SlickEdit is expensive!

Comment: Yeah but that expense is offset by the productivity gains you get over using things like Visual Studio or XCode.