# is there a simple command-line command in linux to justify C++ code?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best C++ Code Formatter/Beautifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841075/best-c-code-formatter-beautifier)

is there a simple command-line command in linux to justify C++ code? I could use an editor, maybe, but I would rather just have some command that spits out indented justified code.

Answer (score 5):

You might find [`astyle`](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) will meet your needs. It's extremely flexible.