# Eclipse C++: Format Source Files in Batch

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, batch-processing

Is it possible for me to use Eclipse to mass-reformat a bunch of C++ files (on the order of a few thousands), without actually having to open every single one in the IDE?

---

**Update:**

A couple people have now posted solutions for the Java IDE, but this does **not** seem to work for the C++ IDE because *there is no "Source" submenu* in Project Explorer. :(

Comment: There was no answer that directly answered the question, so I split up the bounty and the accepted answer between two responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature will be arriving in the next version of CDT (due in June 2011), CDT 8 in Eclipse 3.7.  You can try it now using a milestone build of the platform + cdt: http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/indigo/m6

The bug where this feature was added is here:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=245747

Comment: Transferred the accepted answer here (as much as I don't normally like to do this), since it actually answers the question. :) Thanks a lot for the info!

Comment: the menu option seems to be a no-op :(

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but how about using the [Jindent command line](http://www.jindent.com/custom/docs/jindent-html/Jindent/Invocation.html)?

Assuming you only want to do this once even if the solution is a bit Heath Robinson it should be fine as long as you get the right results.  You can always use Perl to generate a shell script to call the beautifier multiple times with different options on different files/paths if needed.  You could even try AutoHotKey for a truly ugly-but-perhaps-successful approach.

Comment: Is Jindent commercial or free? (Also, I'm using Windows btw.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a C++ beautifier?  This may have already been answered in [Best C++ Code Formatter/Beautifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841075/best-c-code-formatter-beautifier)

Comment: Thanks for the link... unfortunately, I'm specifically looking for getting *Eclipse* to work, but I might very well award the bounty to you if no one finds a way to get Eclipse to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Not specifically for Eclipse...

Our [SD C++ Formatter](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Formatters/CppFormatter.html) reformats source files.

- Two nice features for your problem: you can generate a project file telling it what files to reformat.  It will do them all in batch.
- It uses a full C++ parser to do so, builds an AST, and the prettyprints the result from the AST.  It *can't* break your code.  If you're going to reformat thousands of files, you might appreciate this.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. :(

Comment: Does answer the question. You build a file list. You run the formatter. You don't have to open the files, one at a time, in the IDE. That's what you asked for.  Since you can invoke it a batch script, you can sure configure Eclipse to run it for you, if you insist on running it from the IDE.

Comment: Not really, because the question was how to use ***Eclipse***'s formatter, not an outside formatter. If I was looking for a different code formatter, it wouldn't have been too hard to find on Google. Come to think of it, I might not award the bounty at all if nobody finds a way to do this. :\

Comment: @Mehrdad: OK, if you insist on using Eclipse's formatter, then you're right, it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

In Eclipse 3.0 or newer, you can right click a folder and select Source > Format. That should format all source files in the folder using project specific settings.

Files have to be checked out (and thus be writable) for this to work.

Comment: Someone already put this answer and then removed it; it's for Java, not C++... there's no "Source" submenu in the CDT.

Comment: you are right but for only Eclipse for java. If you download and try it in Eclipse for C++ the menu is not available.