# A Java C source formatter lib?

Tags: java, c, code-formatting

I am generating C code from a domain-specific language using javacc and I would like a FOSS code reformatter library (jar) that I can invoke on the produced source code to make it readable. Anyone know such a beast?

Brownie points for maven dependency entry in answer :)

Comment: I have failed to find a suitable library. (I assume that this is due to weak Google-fu; search suggestions welcome.)

Comment: Java is source wise pretty close to C.  Would a Java reformatting step be ok for your C source?

Comment: I suppose I could try that. There are some macros in there, but not too many. If there is a Java formatter that swallows */&, it might work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given that you are producing C code, try a C beautifier.  If that is suitable, then

[Best C++ Code Formatter/Beautifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841075/best-c-code-formatter-beautifier)

is a question that answers which one.

Good luck on the DSL.  I've done a bunch of them, but using javacup, yacc and spirit rather than JavaCC if you need help, feel free to contact directly