# Replace all tab characters at the beginnings of lines with 8 spaces?

Tags: sed

I just stumbled upon a problem that I find surprisingly difficult. I'd like to replace all tab characters at the beginnings of lines in all *.cc and *.h files with 8 spaces. Something like:

```
sed  's/\t/        /g' -i  *.cc *.h
```

But only for the beginnings of lines. Keep in mind that `sed 's/^\t/      /g'  -i  *.cc *.h` won't do as it doesn't handle the case when the line begins with multiple tabulation characters.

How can I achieve this using sed?

Comment: You probably need a C beautifier.  Check out this [question on Stackoverflow][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841075/best-c-code-formatter-beautifier

Comment: Well, I'd basically like to make this particular change only. Configuring beautifier to do all the job would take a lot of time.

Comment: In regex, the asterisk is used to denote zero or more of the preceding symbol.  So, the following sed command might work, but I didn't test:  
`sed 's/^\t\t*/ /g' -i *.cc *.h`  The ^\t\t* would denote one or more tab characters at the beginning of a line.

Comment: I don't think it will replace multiple tabs with multiple sequences of 8 spaces.

Comment: OK, I understand what you're trying to do now.  I think what you need is a loop that repeatedly executes the command that you originally posted `sed 's/^\t/ /g' -i *.cc *.h` until there are no longer any lines that start with `\t`.  The test condition would be something like `(grep ^\t filename | wc -l)==0`.  Not sure if it would have to be done with a small script, or if it's possible to do it somehow with a clever one-liner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following command:

```
sed ':label s/^\(\(        \)*\)\t/\1        /; t label' -i  *.cc *.h
```

You can read about branching in sed here: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/12/unix-sed-tutorial-6-examples-for-sed-branching-operation/

Answer (score 0):

Using sed

```
sed -r ':a s/(^ {8}*)\t/\1        /;ta'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using,

```
sed -e '/^\t/ s/\t/        /g'
```