# How to auto format code after open file in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

i have a problem with working with a lot of unformating code.

```
Open .cpp file > select all > Ctrl + K + D
```

and i do it time by time. Standart properties of auto format code after: paste from clipboard, type ";", "}", braces and it all is not my case. If it need that files that i opened should be with special named "text_unformated.cpp" - i can do it.

Comment: There are (external) tools  available like e.g. [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Use other tools for batch processing. You don't even need to open files manually. See: [Best C++ Code Formatter/Beautifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841075/best-c-code-formatter-beautifier)