# Using sed/awk to port multiple line in clause to a line?

Tags: awk, sed

I have a code clause in a multiple line  and want port it to one line for example:

```
int j =7;
int k =17;
int p =17;
myFunc(j,
k,
p);
j++;
```

port it to

```
int j =7;
int k =17;
int p =17;
myFunc(j, k, p);
j++;
```

I have a expression that close to what that I need but result is

```
 sed -e '/my/,/;\a/{:a; N; s/\n/ /g; ta}' my file 

int j =7;
int k =17;
int p =17;
myFunc(j, k, p); j++;
```

any idea How to do that?

Comment: use clang format or any other auto format tool, nothing else :)

Comment: I havn't clang. can you help to me do it.

Comment: You _could_ use `sed` or `awk`, but you'll get better results from a more targeted tool - I recommend GNU `indent`.

Comment: You cannot reliably manipulate the text of a programming language without a parser for that language. As @TobySpeight says get a beautifier like `indent`, or `cb` or `uncrustify`, or anything mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841075/best-c-code-formatter-beautifier or just google `C beautifier`.

Comment: I haven't parser and I haven't permission to install it on my workstation I only want to do a small manipulation

Comment: regular expression tool can't not guarantee to deal with a context free grammar without producing any issues. it's better to use a specific tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^my/{:a;/;$/!{N;ba};s/\n/ /g}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want one statement per line and statements are delimited by `;`, you can use this trick:  remove all new lines and replace delimiters with delimiter+newline.

One solution using awk

```
 tr -d '\n' <code | awk -v RS=";" -v ORS=";\n" '1'
```

Obviously, this won't work if you have multi-line statements.